# Correct syntax for connecting to SQL Server in SSMS

Tags: sql-server, tcp

I'm having a difficult time remotely connecting to a server. I apologize if this isn't the correct stack to post on. I'm on a time limit that is running out here.

Each time I try to connect I get

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server.

It also states that my connection timed out. I have tried the following:

- Enabling remote connection in SSMS on the target machine
- Enabling TCP/IP in SS configuration manager
- Checking that port 1433 is enabled under IPALL in SSCM
- Allowing outbound and inbound rules for ports 1433, 433 in TCP and UDP on both target machine and client machine
- Allowing the actual .exe of sql server in the outbound and inbound firewall rules
- Restarting `sqlserver` in `services.msc`

The only thing I can think of is that my syntax for the connection is incorrect.

In SSMS while trying to link the server I add:
`207.97.213.202:1433\733674-DB2\733674-ADMIN` to the linked server field and select SQL Server under the radio button options.

I have tried connecting without the ip address as well

[image]

Comment: What kind of server-name is `207.97.213.202:1433\733674-DB2\733674-ADMIN`? I see an IP address and port, but why are there 2 slashes? Instance names don't contain slashes. BTW, specify a port with a comma, not a colon. Try `207.97.213.202,1433`.

Comment: The `733674-DB2` is the name of the SQL Server instance while the text after the following slash is the username

Comment: I see what you mean, the last portion is not required. That's actually the windows server username

Comment: You could try troubleshooting at the network level. Does `PING 207.97.213.202` return a result? Does `TELNET 207.97.213.202 1433` return a blank screen? (good)

Comment: As first thing, make sure that your SQL server INSTANCE is listening at port 1433 (I would think it allocates ports dynamically for different server instances).

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I did try that and got good results. The problem actually ended up being that rackspace didn't tell us we needed to use an internal IP for our sql server machine while we were trying to use an external ip -_-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your server-name is invalid, on multiple counts:

1. Ports are specified with a comma, not a colon.
2. Login Names do not go into the server-name, they are a separate field

The text entered into the box should be `207.97.213.202,1433\733674-DB2`. Your username will go into the Security page of the wizard, though please use Integrated Authentication where possible.

Comment: I wish I were able to mark this as correct but it still is not working. I just read that rackspace blocks port 1433 by default so am on the phone with them to see if that is the case

Comment: Your answer was indeed correct for the syntax. The problem ended up being we were given the external ip address when we needed the internal to connect to sql server